# RxJava Completabe andThen testing

Tags: rx-java

I have the following RxJava2 Kotlin code:

```
val tester = Completable.complete()
            .andThen(SingleSource<Int> { Single.just(42) })
            .test()        
tester.assertComplete()
tester.assertValue(42)
```

This simulates having a Completable observable (imagine a simple update operation to an API) and then a Single observable (image a get operation on an API). I want to concatenate the two observables in a way that, when the Completable finishes, the Single runs and finally I get the onSuccess event on my observer (the Int 42).

However this test code is not working. The assertion fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Not completed
(latch = 1, values = 0, errors = 0, completions = 0))
```

I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong, I expect that the Completable emits onComplete on subscription, and then the Single subscribes, and my observer (`tester`) gets an onSuccess event with the value 42, but seems that the subscription stays "suspended" not emitting anything.

The idea is similar to the one found in this blog post: https://android.jlelse.eu/making-your-rxjava-intentions-clearer-with-single-and-completable-f064d98d53a8

```
apiClient.updateMyData(myUpdatedData) // a Completable
    .andThen(performOtherOperation()) // a Single<OtherResult>
    .subscribe(otherResult -> {
        // handle otherResult
    }, throwable -> {
        // handle error
    });
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is Kotlin with its ambiguous use of curly braces:

```
.andThen(SingleSource<Int> { Single.just(42) })
```

You create a `SingleSource` that does noting to its `SingleObserver`, but that is hidden by the Kotlin syntax. What you need is plain use:

```
.andThen(Single.just(42))
```

or deferred use

```
.andThen(Single.defer { Single.just(42) })
```

Comment: Thanks akarnokd, for some reason I added that to the code because initially I was doing `.andThen { Single.just(42) }` which was not compiling.